# Можете подсказать, какие известные кодстайлы C++ существуют?

Tags: c++, форматирование-кода

Встал вопрос об оформлении кода, в компании сказали чтобы выбрал\написал кодстайл для моих скриптов, разумеется, найти готовый проще, чем свой расписывать, в Интернете не особо накопал, только отрезками, кто что советует. Посоветуйте стайл или куда копать.

Comment: Главное: Allman + Tabs.

Answer (score 3):

Например:

- [Mozilla](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/coding-style/index.html)
- [LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html)
- [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html)
- [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)
- [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/styleguide/styleguide.md)
- [WebKit](https://www.webkit.org/coding/coding-style.html)

Я бы посоветовал Вам использовать [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). Возьмите за основу один из вышеперечисленных код-стайлов и сгенерируйте конфигурацию:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Затем вручную измените параметры, значения по-умолчанию которых Вас не устроили. Более подробную информацию можете найти по [ссылке](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

---

Про удобность: это ведь очень субъективно. Вы командой должны решить, что Вам подходит.

Comment: мне как начинающему нужен такой который будет понятен разработчикам такого же уровня как и я то есть простой ю за ответ спасибо

Comment: @МишаШишкин, а что Вы понимаете под "понятен"? Ну вот в одном используют два пробела для отступов, а в другом - четыре. В одном добавляют пробел между условным оператором и скобками, а в другом - нет. Я не нахожу здесь оснований для волнения, что кто-то это может не понять.

Comment: @МишаШишкин, код-стайл - это набор правил, которым Вы должны следовать при написании кода. clang-format - это инструмент, который позволяет выполнять автоматическое форматирование. Последний, если он Вам не нужен, можете и не использовать.